# Powershell splatting operator only for accepted parameters?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible, using PowerShell, to use splatting from hashtable when the hashtable contains more entries that the function accepts ?

My use case is to have config objects I pass from one function to another. However, all functions does not require same parameters.

Ex:

```
function Process-Something{
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Owner
    )


}

function Process-SomethingElse{
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Owner,
        [Parameter()]
        [int]$x,
        [Parameter()]
        [int]$y

    )
}


$config = @{
    "Owner" = "Bart Simpson"
    "X" = 10
    "Y" = 20
}

Process-Something @config
Process-SomethingElse @config
```

It fails with these error:

```
Process-Something : Cannot find a matching parameter « Y ».
```

The idea is to avoid specifying individual properties for each functions.

Comment: No. The purpose of creating parameter definitions is to have functions throw an error when they're passed invalid arguments. If you want to be able to throw arbitrary arguments at a function you need to remove the parameter definition and have the function sort out `$args` by itself.

Comment: A pscustomobject, and some valuefrompipeline attributes on your parameters could give you the desired outcome...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Ansgar is stating in the comments, the whole idea of having defined your parameters, is to get validation. When you are splatting parameters to your function, you are **forcing** them to the function. So if a given property of your hashtable doesn't exist as a parameter, you will get an error - just like it is intended.

What you **can** do, is going into a PSCustomObject and utilize the pipe. If you set all you parameters to accept value from the pipeline, using property name (`ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true`), then you can actually get the desired behavior.

First I'm redefining your different functions, to have the `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true` parameter attribute configured.

```
function Process-Something{
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$Owner
    )

    $PSBoundParameters
}

function Process-SomethingElse{
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [string]$Owner,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [int]$x,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [int]$y

    )

    $PSBoundParameters
}
```

With that in place, I'm able to create a hashtable like your example, convert it to a PSCustomObject, and now I can pipe that new object to the different methods and have them pick up only the properties that they need.

I included the `PSBoundParameters` to showcase that they get what they expect.
Testing is done like this:

```
$config = @{
    "Owner" = "Bart Simpson"
    "X" = 10
    "Y" = 20
}

$psConfig = [PSCustomObject]$config

$psConfig | Process-Something

$psConfig | Process-SomethingElse
```

[image]

Comment: But I think OP expects the function `Process-Something` to have the Owner set what it doesn't. As you reversed the order of the functions I have the wierd result `First test` with an empty line and the result of `Process-SomethingElse` following `Second test`.

Comment: @LotPings I re-created the test, and I can't seem to find any issues. Will remove the `Write-Host` if it makes things unclear. Will updated with a image as well - then we have something to relate to.

Comment: Sorry, after an unexpected windows restart I get [both outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUs1u.png) I'll remove my comment soon.

Comment: Thanks! it works as expected. FYI, you can cast a Hashtable to a PSCustomObject simply : `$ht = @{ X = 1; Y = 2 };[PSCustomObject]$ht`

Comment: If the solution works, you should accept the answer to reflect that :) Will function is used to different objects and I had it laying around. You are right that the [PSCustomObject] cast works in your scenario. Will update the answer.